# Loop through two dates to get values

Tags: mysql

I have a table that holds entries when the value changes, however I now have a need to get the value for each day between two dates.

So in the database I have the following:

```
2015-10-17  25
2015-10-12  20
2015-10-01  5
```

What I need is to get the values for the entire month

```
2015-10-01  5
2015-10-02  5
....
2015-10-12  20
2015-10-13  20
```

How would I achieve this?  I have the below code

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca447e/1/0

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMonthVals(IN StartDate DATETIME, IN EndDate DATETIME) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE CurrentDate DATETIME;
    SET @CurrentDate = StartDate;

    label1: WHILE @CurrentDate < @EndDate DO
        SELECT @CurrentDate, DVal FROM Table1 WHERE MDate <= @CurrentDate ORDER BY MDate DESC LIMIT 1;
        SET @CurrentDate = DATE_ADD(CurrentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE label1;
END;



CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `MDate` varchar(10), `DVal` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `MDate`, `DVal`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-10-17', 25),
    (2, '2015-10-12', 20),
    (3, '2015-10-01', 5)
;
CALL sp_GetMonthVals('2015-10-01', '2015-10-31');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to achieve this using the below, if anyone can improve the query then I'll accept their answer

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_GetMonthVals;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_GetMonthVals(IN StartDate DATETIME, IN EndDate DATETIME) 
BEGIN 

    DECLARE CurrentDate DATETIME;
    SET @CurrentDate = StartDate;

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _tmpMonthVals;
    CREATE TABLE _tmpMonthVals (`MDate` DATETIME, `DVal` int);

    label1: WHILE @CurrentDate < EndDate DO
        INSERT INTO _tmpMonthVals SELECT @CurrentDate, DVal FROM Table1 WHERE MDate <= @CurrentDate ORDER BY MDate DESC LIMIT 1;
        SET @CurrentDate = DATE_ADD(@CurrentDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
    END WHILE label1;
    SELECT * FROM _tmpMonthVals;
END//
DELIMITER ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Table1
    (`id` int, `MDate` DATETIME, `DVal` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `MDate`, `DVal`)
VALUES
    (1, '2015-10-17', 25),
    (2, '2015-10-12', 20),
    (3, '2015-10-01', 5);

CALL sp_GetMonthVals('2015-10-01', '2015-10-31');
```